# run javascript from textarea n times

Tags: javascript, jquery

working code http://codepen.io/one2gov/pen/XNqyzB?editors=1111
this code runs all lines of code, instead of just one. What's wrong?

```
oldVal = $("#fname").val();

lines = $("#fname").val().split(';');
lines.forEach(function(i, idx, array) {
    if (idx == lines.length - 1) {
        return;
    }
    element = $("<textarea></textarea>").attr({ 'id': '' + idx + '', 'class': "textar", 'style': "" }).html(idx+1);

    $("body").append(element)
});

$("#checkBtn").click(function() {

    $('textarea.textar').each(function(i, obj) {
        numbers = this.value;
        numbers = numbers*1;

        lines.forEach(function(i, idx) {
         test = lines[idx];
            if (idx == lines.length - 1) {
                return;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
                //console.log(numbers);
                eval(test);

            }

        })
    });
});
```

The goal is to run lines of code as many times, as number in the textarea on the left of the line.
I am expecting to see in the console first line of code fires one time, and second one 2 times. But instead I am getting results from both numbers on all lines.

Here is the link with demo, that works as it should (but variables are fake) http://codepen.io/one2gov/pen/WoJyvB?editors=1011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `checkBtn` click to:

```
$("#checkBtn").click(function() {
    $('textarea.textar').each(function(i, obj) {
        var numbers = this.value;
        numbers = numbers*1;

        // get only the current line
        var test = lines[i];

        // execute current line 'numbers' times
        for (var j = 0; j < numbers; j++) {
            eval(test);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: So.. i made it harder for no reason.. That did it, I wll accept your answer when it will let me. Thank you, Bruno!

Comment: You are wellcome!